# When grouping a JSON array of objects by the first character in a value, how can I group all characters that start with a number into the same group?

Tags: javascript, json

I've been tinkering with an issue where I have some JSON data and I want to group the objects based off the first letter of their "Name" value.

I was able to accomplish this with an array sort function. But one thing I am also trying to accomplish is have it so that any item that starts with a number (or any non alphabetical value) should be grouped into a separate group.

Right now everything is grouped by Letter **and** number.

Here is some sample JSON:

```
[{
    "Id": 83107,
    "Name": "10-11",
},
{
    "Id": 83107,
    "Name": "Bill",
},
{
    "Id": 83107,
    "Name": "Jim",
},
{
    "Id": 83107,
    "Name": "7-11",
},
{
    "Id": 83107,
    "Name": "Walgreens",
},
{
    "Id": 83107,
    "Name": "Apple",
},
}]
```

And here's the output I am getting:

```
{
   "1":[
      {
         "Id":83107,
         "Name":"10-11"
      }
   ],
   "7":[
      {
         "Id":83107,
         "Name":"7-11"
      }
   ],
   "A":[
      {
         "Id":83107,
         "Name":"Apple"
      }
   ],
   "B":[
      {
         "Id":83107,
         "Name":"Bill"
      }
   ],
   "J":[
      {
         "Id":83107,
         "Name":"Jim"
      }
   ],
   "W":[
      {
         "Id":83107,
         "Name":"Walgreens"
      }
   ]
}
```

What I'd like to do is put all the non-alphabet values into their own group so they would all fall under a group named '#'

Here is the reduce function that I currently use:

```
var dataJSON = [{
        "Id": 83107,
        "Name": "10-11",
    },
    {
        "Id": 83107,
        "Name": "Bill",
    },
    {
        "Id": 83107,
        "Name": "Jim",
    },
    {
        "Id": 83107,
        "Name": "7-11",
    },
    {
        "Id": 83107,
        "Name": "Walgreens",
    },
    {
        "Id": 83107,
        "Name": "Apple",
    },
    }];

dataJSON.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.Name[0].localeCompare(b.Name[0]);
});

var result = {};

for (var i = 0; i < dataJSON.length; i++) {
  var c = dataJSON[i].Name[0].toUpperCase();
  if (result[c] && result[c].length >= 0)

    result[c].push(dataJSON[i]);

  else {

    result[c] = [];
    result[c].push(dataJSON[i]);

  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What you have in the question is not JSON; it is an object literal expression.  They look very similar.  In JS code, JSON is always a string.

Comment: You could build a map of numbers: `const nbGroup = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`. Then you can write `const isNb = result[C] in nbGroup` or `const isNb = resultC === "0" || nbGroup[result[C]]` (beware of zero which is falsy). You could also use JavaScript `Set`, sets are made so that you can easily check if an item belongs to it, ie if your letter belongs to the set of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just modify your code to check if the first letter of the name is a number then add it to the `#` group in your sorted data.

Your code would look  something like this

```js
for (var i = 0; i < dataJSON.length; i++) {
  var c = dataJSON[i].Name[0];
  if(isNaN(parseInt(c))){
    if (result[c] && result[c].length >= 0){
      result[c].push(dataJSON[i]);
    } else {
      result[c] = [dataJSON[i]];
    }
  } else {
    if(result['#'] && result['#'].length >= 0){
      result['#'].push(dataJSON[i]);
    } else {
      result['#'] = [dataJSON[i]];
    }
  }
}
```

### NOTE

This will lead to `result` having the `#` key, but within that key the items will be sorted by the first digit of the number. So the object with the key `Name` as `"10-11"` will go before the object with the key `Name` as `"7-11"`

Running my code with your `dataJSON` gives this `result`

```js
{
  "#" : [
    {
      "Id": 83107, 
      "Name": "10-11"
    },
    {
      "Id": 83107, 
      "Name": "7-11"
    }
  ],
  "A" : [
    {
      "Id":83107,
      "Name":"Apple"
    }
   ],
   "B" : [
    {
      "Id":83107,
      "Name":"Bill"
    }
   ],
   "J" : [
    {
       "Id":83107,
       "Name":"Jim"
    }
   ],
   "W" : [
    {
       "Id":83107,
       "Name":"Walgreens"
    }
   ]
}
```

Comment: @interesting_coderoom it would be helpful for future readers if you could accept the above answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Apologies I had to deal with an unexpected family emergency. Your solution was perfect and I appreciate your help immensely.